# react native custom drawer navigator

Tags: reactjs, navigation

hi i just started learning react native!
trying to make a custom drawer navigator
i have created a component for the drawercontent of the
drawer navigator as described in the react navigation webiste
and then added that component to the drawer itself like this which i
don't understand why we add props like that to the drawer??!!

```
import React from 'react'
import {View,Text} from 'react-native'
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import MainViewHome from './mainViewHome'
import mainViewArticles from './mainViewArticles'
import DrawerContent from './drawerContent'

const drawer=createDrawerNavigator();

export default function MainView(){
    return(
            <drawer1.Navigator drawerContent={props=><MainViewDrawer {...props}/>}>
                <drawer.Screen name='home' component={MainViewHome}/>
                <drawer.Screen name='articles' component={mainViewArticles}/>
            </drawer1.Navigator>
    )
}
```

appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i don't understand why we add props like that to the drawer??!!

**drawerContent** receives following props by default:

- state
- navigation
- descriptors
- progress

See [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawercontent)

Now imagine that you want to pass more props to your MainViewDrawer component :

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import MainViewDrawer from './MainViewDrawer';
...

const drawer =createDrawerNavigator();

export default function MainView(){
    const [newProps, setNewProps] = useState('Hello world');

    return(
            <drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props=><MainViewDrawer {...props} newProps={newProps} />}>
                ...
            </drawer.Navigator>
    )
};
```